# Resources for learning functional programming/Haskell for the mathematically inclined.

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, type-theory

I am a math student wanting to learn some functional programming with Haskell. From what I understand, many type theory concepts are analogous, even equivalent, to category theory concepts (e.g. Monads are *Monads*). Is there some resource which serves as an introduction to FP with Haskell that is oriented towards mathematicians? It would be nice to have a clear path to transport my intuition about category theory.

Comment: Some of the analogies used in Haskell to categorical concepts are a bit odd, which to my understanding can actually make it harder to understand how to use them when you already understand categorical concepts. For example, to Haskell, a Functor is a type constructor f (the mapping from objects to objects) and a function fmap (the mapping from arrows to arrows), where fmap satisfies the axioms you know for mapping arrows to arrows.

Comment: But the type constructor needn't have an *object* constructor, so it is not necessarily clear from the Functor axioms that the category given by f(Hask) actually means anything (here Hask is the category of Haskell types). The other weird thing is that the category f(Hask) is always a subcategory of Hask; there are no functors from Hask to other categories, from Haskell's perspective. Things get weirder still when you get to what Haskell calls monads.

Comment: Some of the Haskell introduction textbooks use maths expressions more than others. one I read ages ago had an emphasis on learning lambda calculus first and there was a whole bunch of exercises to do which helped understand the order of operations in lambda calculus. I guess it helped… hard to say and I forget the math now completely! Perhaps anybody reading this who want's a maths intro to Haskell should preview a bunch of the Haskell intro books or ask on Haskell channel of the FP Discord or Haskell Beginners channel on the Haskell Stack

Answer (score 1):

## Youtube and Blogs

1. Video course on introducing Logic and Haskell by Marius Furter which maybe of [interest](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0HImO-me_sg&list=PLd8NbPjkXPliojM8YMN3z3o9--zXwti8Z).
2. [Wiki books](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell)
3. [Bartosz Milweski's blog](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/10/28/category-theory-for-programmers-the-preface/)
4. [This google talk tries to introduce Haskell in three hours](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cTN1Qar4HSw)
5. [The Haskell Playlist by Tsoding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h_D4P-KRNKs&list=PLguYJK7ydFE4aS8fq4D6DqjF6qsysxTnx) is quite nice. It doesn't really go into the mathy part of Haskell, but it gives a lot of clarity and are nice follow along tutorials. Basically sort of like an adult version of Dora the explorer but for learning Haskell.

## Specific topics

To my understanding one needs a good understanding of type theory, lambda calculus, and perhaps to a lesser extent, Category theory to understand Haskell.

1. The SEP on [Alonzo Church](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/church/) is a nice starting point for Lambda Calculus
2. [Naive Type theory talk by Thorsten AltenKirch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNG53SA4n48)
3. The presentation by [Richard Southwell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEz8DGIjXQI) on Type theory is an example of exemplary exposition. I suggest skipping the first five to six minutes of the linked video as the production quality is poor then, but quickly ramps up afterwards. Warning: This video assumes very basic Category Theory, however, he also has videos on that elsewhere on his channel.
4. The most clearest explanation I found of [monads](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhuHCtR3xq8). I recommend skipping the first 20 minutes, because the person explaining assumes you don't even know what a function composition is (lol).

---

## Specific books

1. Haskell School of Music: This is a nice book I found , but one complaint is, that the module that the book uses for teaching music doesn't support digital signal processing or something.
2. An Introduction to Functional Programming through Lambda Calculus: Thick book, but it is very easy to read and can be read like a novel. I read till half of it, and it gave me the most amount of understanding in what Lambda Calculus is.
3. Types and Programming Languages by Benjamin C Pierce.: This seems to be a nice book for those who wants to understand type theory in more detail. Although I bored myself reading this book)
4. Thinking Functionally with Haskell: This book has some mathematical clarity relative to some other sources of Haskell I found on the internet, but the problem is, it feels quite rushed. You'd have to adjust for it by reading the book slower and going over one section again and again, but this was a bit difficult to adjust for me.

---

## Remark:

I found this Vladimir Voevodosky quote relevant in regards to type theory when talking about how he learned to read the text on type theory written by computer scientists and logicians:

## "You should never try to figure out how to prove this or that statement"

[Source 3:15](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e20dCMrAYOM)

Comment: Why the downvote?